# MultiValueDictKeyError when deleting related inline records in another tab

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

I'll try to be as concise as possible.

**Background**

I have a model `Person` which has a `ForeignKey` to model `Document`. Each `Person` can only have one `Document` but, as you may already know, each `Document` can be linked to many `Person`s.

In the `Document`'s Admin form I have the `Person`s associated to the `Document` displayed inline. I can edit, add or delete the `Person`s right there.

**Problem**

Following these steps I get the error:

1. I open the Admin edit form for a `Document`. Let's call it *Document
   A*. This `Document` has two `Person`s associated, let's call them *John
   Doe* and *Jane Doe*. You can see them there (inline) in the form and
   the fields are editable, but I don't touch them.
2. I open another tab and go straight to the `Person`s list and delete
   *Jane Doe*.
3. I get back to the first tab (the `Document`'s edit form) and click on
   "*Save and continue editing*".
4. The form is sent and I get a generic error at the top (something
   like) "*Please, fix the following errors*". But the form shows no
   errors (next to the fields) to correct and, obviously, the record
   for *Jane Doe* isn't displayed.
5. I click again on "*Save and continue editing*" and when the form is
   sent I get the error "`MultiValueDictKeyError: "u'person_set-1-id'"`".

**Ideal solution**

I'd like to be able to display a custom error in the middle stage (when the first error appears, after the first save), saying something like "*A person associated with this Document was deleted while you were editing it*". Also, preventing the final error is highly desirable.

**Error dump**

```
MultiValueDictKeyError at /admin/persons/document/1145/

"u'person_set-1-id'"

Request Method:     POST
Request URL:    http://localhost:8000/admin/persons/document/1145/
Django Version:     1.7.7
Exception Type:     MultiValueDictKeyError
Exception Value:    

"u'person_set-1-id'"

Exception Location:     /__PATH__/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/datastructures.py in __getitem__, line 319
Python Executable:  /__PATH__/bin/python
Python Version:     2.7.15
Python Path:    

['/__PATH__/test/test/apps',
 '/__PATH__/test',
 '/__PATH__/lib/python2.7',
 '/__PATH__/lib/python2.7/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu',
 '/__PATH__/lib/python2.7/lib-tk',
 '/__PATH__/lib/python2.7/lib-old',
 '/__PATH__/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk',
 '/__PATH__/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages',
 '/__PATH__/src/django-smart-selects',
 '/__PATH__/lib/python2.7/site-packages',
 '/__PATH__/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/odf',
 '/__PATH__/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/odf',
 '/__PATH__/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/odf',
 '/__PATH__/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/odf',
 '/__PATH__/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/odf',
 '/__PATH__/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/odf',
 '/__PATH__/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/odf',
 '/__PATH__/test']

Server time:    Mar, 29 Ene 2019 11:52:18 -0300

Environment:


Request Method: POST
Request URL: http://localhost:8000/admin/persons/document/1145/

Django Version: 1.7.7
Python Version: 2.7.15
Installed Applications:
('salmonella',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.sites',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'django.contrib.admin',
 'crispy_forms',
 'test.apps.persons',
 'captcha',
 'django_countries',
 'django_extensions',
 'import_export',
 'django_object_actions',
 'widget_tweaks',
 'smart_selects',
 'daterange_filter',
 'compressor',
 'auditlog')
Installed Middleware:
('django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
 'auditlog.middleware.AuditlogMiddleware')


Traceback:
File "/__PATH__/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  111.                     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "/__PATH__/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/options.py" in wrapper
  583.                 return self.admin_site.admin_view(view)(*args, **kwargs)
File "/__PATH__/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py" in _wrapped_view
  105.                     response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/__PATH__/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/views/decorators/cache.py" in _wrapped_view_func
  52.         response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/__PATH__/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/sites.py" in inner
  206.             return view(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/__PATH__/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/options.py" in change_view
  1456.         return self.changeform_view(request, object_id, form_url, extra_context)
File "/__PATH__/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py" in _wrapper
  29.             return bound_func(*args, **kwargs)
File "/__PATH__/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py" in _wrapped_view
  105.                     response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/__PATH__/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py" in bound_func
  25.                 return func.__get__(self, type(self))(*args2, **kwargs2)
File "/__PATH__/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/transaction.py" in inner
  394.                 return func(*args, **kwargs)
File "/__PATH__/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/options.py" in changeform_view
  1403.             if all_valid(formsets) and form_validated:
File "/__PATH__/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/forms/formsets.py" in all_valid
  438.         if not formset.is_valid():
File "/__PATH__/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/forms/formsets.py" in is_valid
  303.         self.errors
File "/__PATH__/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/forms/formsets.py" in errors
  277.             self.full_clean()
File "/__PATH__/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/forms/formsets.py" in full_clean
  325.             form = self.forms[i]
File "/__PATH__/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py" in __get__
  55.         res = instance.__dict__[self.func.__name__] = self.func(instance)
File "/__PATH__/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/forms/formsets.py" in forms
  141.         forms = [self._construct_form(i) for i in xrange(self.total_form_count())]
File "/__PATH__/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/forms/models.py" in _construct_form
  868.         form = super(BaseInlineFormSet, self)._construct_form(i, **kwargs)
File "/__PATH__/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/forms/models.py" in _construct_form
  581.             pk = self.data[pk_key]
File "/__PATH__/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/datastructures.py" in __getitem__
  319.             raise MultiValueDictKeyError(repr(key))

Exception Type: MultiValueDictKeyError at /admin/persons/document/1145/
Exception Value: "u'person_set-1-id'"
```

**UPDATE**

I'm adding the definitions for models Person and Document.

```
class Document(models.Model):
    creation_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=300, null=True, blank=True)

class Person(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=300)
    document = models.ForeignKey(Document)
```

**UPDATE 2**

One important thing I noticed is that, in the first error page (after the first submission of *Document A* form) the hidden inputs like `person_set-TOTAL_FORMS` and `person_set-INITIAL_FORMS` are set to 2 while they should be set to 1 (the actual number of persons). Obviously this happens because the submitted data doesn't reflect the actual database state.

Comment: It would have been much better if you could just provide the code instead of explaining your logic.

Comment: Thank you, I just added the code for both models in the description.

Comment: I don't get you. When you go back to `Document` after deleting the `Person` *Jane Doe* you say "I click on Save and editing" are you just clicking that button or editing the `Document A` lets say setting it to `Document B` and hitting the button ?

Comment: No, the _Document A_ tab is left untouched, nothing is changed. The problem here is that the `Person` disappears from the model/database, yet the _Document A_ form still thinks it's there. When the _Document A_ form is submitted it takes with it information about a _Jane Doe_ that isn't there anymore.

One important thing I noticed (I'll add it to the description) is that, in the first error page (after the first submission of _Document A_ form) the hidden inputs like person_set-TOTAL_FORMS are set to 2 while it should be set to 1 (the actual number of persons).